# Where can I get a prebuilt tcldot dll for Windows?

Tags: windows, tcl, graphviz

I have built a tcl program using tcldot on MacOS. I have to supply it to someone who uses Windows 7, but I do not have development tools for Windows 7.

The prebuilt binaries for graphviz at http://www.graphviz.org/Download..php for MacOS contain what I need (at /usr/local/lib/graphviz/tcl), but I cannot find the corresponding dll in the prebuilt binary for Windows.

The link at http://www.isn-oldenburg.de/~schlenk/tcl/tcldot/ seems dead.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a good look around and can't find a prebuilt online anywhere. The best I can suggest is to get a free build chain for Windows (I've used mingw in the past, but there are others) and build it yourself. Not a perfect solution by any means.

Comment: Donal thanks for the reply. I will look into mingw, but the issue is that I do not have ready access to a Windows machine. I guess that I will have to "borrow" one to install mingw. But of course if I borrow one I could just as well install the free version of Visual Studio.  :-)